# jquery class selector with css() does not seem to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click the link(Anasayfa), function doesn't work. There is no change. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function anasayfa() {
            $( '.gributon1' ) . css({ "background-color": "red"  });
        }
</script>

....

<div class="gributon1"></div>

....

<a href="" onclick="anasayfa()"> Anasayfa </a>
```

Comment: What context are you doing this in, what browser etc

Comment: Oh, the question got changed while I was writing my comment

Comment: I've voted to close because, as the description says, this question is unlikely to help anyone in the future. In future, please include, at the very least, a description of the problem, including what you mean by “doesn't work”.

Comment: I deleted my answer cuz I got 2 downvotes. Apparently people frown upon the idea that the OP should be including the several hundred bug-fixes (thanks to the JQuery team) in his debugging venture before coming to stackoverflow...

Comment: makcbn look at @saeed's answer.

Comment: i looked saaed' s answer but i couldt solve the problem i include some text in div also

Answer (score 3):

it works http://jsfiddle.net/BeYty/

Answer (score 1):

You need to return false from your link's onclick or the page will refresh since you are clicking on a link to href "" which is the current page.

`<a href="" onclick="anasayfa() return false;"> Anasayfa </a>`

Answer (score 1):

Your Div is empty and you can't see it's changes, and the href value of your link must be set to "javascript:void" in order not to refresh the page.
somthing like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function anasayfa() {
           $( '.gributon1' ) . css({ "background-color": "red"  });
        }
</script>
...
<div class="gributon1">..</div>
....
<a href="javascript:void" onclick="anasayfa()"> Anasayfa </a>
```

Comment: This is the right answer. The OPs code works, but he just doesn't know it because he hasn't included any text in there.

Comment: but I tried this code and it's working. Are u sure your javascript is not off? put a simple alarm command and check your javascript

Comment: yeah i am sure javascript is not of

Comment: then put a simple alarm command in anasayfa function to checkif it is called.

Comment: yeah it is working alert( "nfşalsfnaşfç" ); i tried in anasayfa function but css code doesnt work :(

Comment: And are you sure you changed the href attribute as I told? does your page refresh after click Ok on alert?

Comment: $( '.gributon1' ) . toggle();   this is working for example but css code doesnt work i did everything you told

Answer (score 0):

try by making the following two changes to your code

1. modify your `href` to `<a href="#"></a>`
2. place some text inside the `div`

i hope you are placing your code inside the `<head>//your script here</head>`

```
<div class="gributon1">some text</div>


<a href="#" onclick="anasayfa()"> Anasayfa </a>
```

and the script part remains the same

```
function anasayfa() {
$('.gributon1' ).css({"backgroundColor":"Red"});
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/BeYty/34/

Comment: Is that going to help here, as the function is called by a click event, useful to know (for the OP) but not why it's not working (allegedly)

Comment: @Antony Scott you are right fell free to edit my answer and add the ddetails i'll approve it or you can make your own answer